# Understanding base58check encoding of a Tezos public key

Tags: key, base58

I would like to fully understand how `base58` encoding for a  Tezos public key works, what are specific parts of an encoded `edpk` version and what do they stand for.

I attempted to create such key manually by generating random `ed25519` bytes and prepending `[13, 15, 37, 217]` bytes to that. A `base58check` encoded version looks as follows:

`edpku3g7CeTEvSKhxipD4Q2B6EiEP8cR323u8PFmGFgKRVRvCneEmT`

My questions are:

- Which parts of an encoded string are Tezos-specific things? For example - is it possible to map prefix bytes to characters in the encoded string?
- Which part is a `base58check` checksum?

I appreciate that some answers might not be related not to Tezos knowledge but to cryptography, specifically to how `base58check` works. In such case, apart from the answers I'd appreciate links to read up on.

Thanks,
K

---

EDIT after Athur B's comment:

Turns out a `1` means I'm doing something wrong. I would like to learn what is it, then :) . I am using a following nodejs code to generate my key:

```
import * as ed25519 from "ed25519";
import crypto from "crypto";

const seed = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const keyPair = ed25519.MakeKeypair(seed);
const pubKeyBytes = keyPair.publicKey;

const tezosPublicKeyPrefix = Buffer.from([13, 15, 37, 217]);
const prefixedPublicKey = Buffer.concat([tezosPublicKeyPrefix, pubKeyBytes]);
const base58checkEncoded = base58check.encode(prefixedPublicKey);

console.log('base58 pub key: ' + base58checkEncoded);
```

it prints:

```
base58 pub key: 1edpkubvws8V7KQcrSFMu3SjXU5PTbJASgJrdfzXd37rEBzWv9uKWvV
```

---

EDIT after resolving leading `1` issue

I managed to fix a leading `1` issue! The problem was, a [`base58check` lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base58check) that I was using for encoding was bugged! Switching to [bs58check lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58check) helped and my code generated a correct key (no leading `1`) . I guess I should have looked at weekly downloads as it's 68k vs 2k!

Anyway, I will change my question now that the `1` is not there anymore.

---

Topics for other people wanting to learn of things around that issue:

[Format of public key, signature and key_hash literals](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/442/format-of-public-key-signature-and-key-hash-literals)

[How to hash a Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-hash-a-tezos-public-key)

[How to convert ed25519 bytes to Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-convert-ed25519-bytes-to-tezos-public-key)

Comment: There's no 1 in front of edpk, if you're getting a 1 you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer and posted a code sample I'm using to generate the key. What seems to be amiss?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this library for Tezos, written in Go. [This function](https://github.com/goat-systems/go-tezos/blob/61062f5d118123f3cb582ffa9a72a37c2c329bc8/account/account.go#L123) in particular generates a new wallet from random bytes (mnemonic and password can both be considered as random bytes) and creates an unencrypted secret key, public key, and public address.

Comment: If javascript is more your style, check out https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/dist/eztz.cli.js#L274

Comment: Thank you for that. Sadly, in my use case I need to base on `ed25519` bytes, not on mnemonics.

Comment: As I said in the post above, treat mnemonics as random bytes. It doesn't have to be words, it can be random bytes.

Comment: Tried that, got the same result - a `base58check` encoded string starting with `1edpk`  and 55 characters long, which is incorrect.

Comment: Link rot advice: use the commit hash instead of the tag `master` when referencing github git repositories for obvious reasons

Comment: [go link](https://github.com/goat-systems/go-tezos/blob/61062f5d118123f3cb582ffa9a72a37c2c329bc8/account/account.go#L123) [javascript link](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/cfdc4fcfc891f4f4f077c3056f414476dde3610b/dist/eztz.cli.js#L274)